# logstash elasticsearch and kibana does not show results

Tags: elasticsearch

i have logstash elasticsearch and kibana3 in one machine. I have install it as bundle.
Everything looks normal but no results in kibana interface.

"No results There were no results because no indices were found that match your selected time span"
Redis-cli Lpop shown proggress so i assume ti works>
When i type in my browser
 `http://172.16.1.178:9200/logstash-2014.01.27/_mapping?pretty=true`
I get

```
{
  "error" : "RemoteTransportException[Failed to deserialize exception response from stream]; nested: TransportSerializationException[Failed to deserialize exception response from stream]; nested: StreamCorruptedException[unexpected end of block data]; ",
  "status" : 500
}
```

Can you help?

Thanks

Comment: Which elasticsearch version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue when you use different versions of java on different machines. It doesn't seem to be your case thought. [Take a look at it](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3145#issuecomment-27455667) for more details.

> This is due to a bug in Java where they changed how InetAddress gets serialized over the wire sadly. ES uses Java serialization only when it serializes exception over the wire, and sadly that causes it.

via [this post](http://jontai.me/blog/2013/06/elasticsearch-remotetransportexception-failed-to-deserialize-exception-response-from-stream/#comment-381).